# App jQuery funciona em Localhost, Dispositivos Móveis, mas não funciona em navegadores

Tags: jquery, html5

Desenvolvi uma pequena aplicação utilizando HTML5 e jQuery.

Ela funciona perfeitamente em localhost. Fiz o upload do código todo, e uma rotina específica 
não funcionou em nenhum dos navegadores (Chrome, Firefox ou Opera).

Testei no Safari do iPhone e também não funcionou. Imaginei que pudesse ter esquecido de subir 
algum arquivo, mas no último teste, quando criei um atalho da página no iPhone, funcionou perfeitamente.

Enfim, testei no Chrome do Android e também funcionou sem nenhum problema.

Alguém já passou por uma situação semelhante?

Fiz estes dois testes e ambos não geraram nada no console. Creio que o problema possa estar aqui:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pagRanking', function() {
    console.log('before show');
})

$(document).on('pageshow', '#pagRanking', function() {
    console.log('show');
})
```

Comment: Já verificaste o caminho para o jQuery? Provavelmente ele não está a ser carregado e o teu código não funciona. Experimenta isto antes desse código que tens ai, fora dessas funções: `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { console.log('jQuery não foi carregado!'); } else { console.log('jQuery Carregado!'); }` para ver se o jQuery está carregado ou não!

Comment: você está utilizando algum servidor para fornecer os arquivos ou é apenas uma página estática? no inspetor de elementos do seu navegador você consegue ver se ele conseguiu pegar estes arquivos na aba `network`?

Comment: O jQuery está carregado.

Comment: Os arquivos também são carregados na aba network, como deveriam, no entanto o arquivo JS parece não ter se atualizado. Tentei um CTRL+F5 (obviamente), mas ele parece não se alterar.

Answer (score 1):

`pagebeforeshow` e `pageshow`, num todo, não são compatíveis com navegadores de mesa. Para tal, opte por `$(document).ready(...);` ou `$(window).on('load', ...);`.

Comment: Eu substituí o $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pagRanking', function() { console.log('before show'); }) por $(document).on('load', '#pagRanking', function() {    console.log('before show'); }) e deixou de funcionar em todos os dispositivos.

Comment: Alexandre, tenta: `$(document).ready(function () { console.log('before document is ready'); });`

Comment: Funcionou, Guilherme, mas eu tive que manter os eventos pagebeforeshow e pageshow, pois o load não disparou nem um console.log.

Comment: Não entendi. Onde que o "`load`" não disparou nenhum `console.log`? Para ser responsivo, você pode usar também o `$(window).on('load', function () { console.log('hi!'); });`.

Comment: Este load deu certo, mas o $(document).on('load', '#pagRanking', function() { console.log('before show'); }) não. Devo trocar o 'document' por 'window'?

Comment: Sim, Alexandre. Eles faem coisas diferentes. O `document` significa DOM. `document` e `ready` significa que você vai executar algo quando o DOM for carregado; Por outro lado, o `window` e `load` se traduz por executar algo assim que a janela for carregada, independente do DOM estar pronto ou não.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { console.log('before document is ready'); });`    pode ser substituído por    `$(function () { console.log('before document is ready'); });`    (trocando `$(document).ready`somente por `$`)   você pode entender um pouco melhor em [Jquery Document Ready em EN](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Nem todos os browser sao compativeis com os eventos `pageshow` e `pagebeforeshow`.
Podes verificar esta compatibilidade assim:

```
if(window.onpageshow|| window.onpageshow=== null){
   window.addEventListener('pageshow', showFunction, false);
} else {
   window.addEventListener('load', showFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: Todos os navegadores retornaram TRUE para esta verificação, ou seja, todos aceitam estes eventos. Mas como eu estou em condições ideiais (navegadores super atualizados), talvez seja interessante substituí-los por um evento mais certeiro.